# How to setup `pyi_out` path when using with rules-proto-grpc?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I'm using rules-proto-grpc's [`python_grpc_library`](https://rules-proto-grpc.com/en/latest/lang/python.html#python-grpc-library) rule to compile python files in my bazel project.

As protoc generated python files use dynamic construction of classes, I want to use the `--pyi_out=` option to generate python stub file to make the IDE know the typing and do typing check.

However, I'm confused how to setup the path properly in the rule.

e.g. my bazel like

```
           python_grpc_library(
                name = label,
                protos = protos,
                visibility = visibility,
                extra_protoc_args = [
                    "--pyi_out=??",
                ],
                deps = py_lib_deps,
            )
```

I tried `.` and some abs path, both not working. Wondering  has similar setup before？

When I directly use the protoc command outside of bazel, it works.

--